# How to Select a value from the many table in a 1:many relationship?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

## Example Tables:

one table

| ID | User |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Trey |
| 2 | Not Trey |

many table

| ID | product_purchased | purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | private jet | y |
| 1 | mega yacht | N |

For this situation I want to get this end result

| ID | User | purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Trey | private jet |
| 2 | Not Trey |  |

Comment: Do you want a measure or calculated column? What if there are multiple values on the many side? Do you want the first, last or have them all concatenated?

Comment: @DavidBacci Calculated column. Filter by the purchased column, only one will have value y and that is the one I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Add a calculated column as follows:

```
Column = MAXX( FILTER(RELATEDTABLE(Purchase), Purchase[purchased] = "Y"), Purchase[product_purchased])
```

Answer (score 1):

another option:

Product = calculate(selectedvalue('many'[product_purchased]),filter(relatedtable('many'),'many'[purchased]="Y"))